# Putting top-level modules in a "lib" directory

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

#### Context

I have a project set up like this

```
setup.py
MANIFEST.in
lib/
    foo.py
    bar.py
magic/
    __init__.py
    alchemy.py
    submagic/
        __init__.py
        wizard.py
```

with this `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    py_modules=['foo', 'bar'],
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['lib', 'lib.*']),
    package_dir={'foo': 'lib', 'bar': 'lib'}
)
```

and `MANIFEST.in`

```
graft magic
graft lib
```

#### Problem

When I use `pip install`, I end up with the modules `lib.foo` and `lib.bar` instead of top-level modules `foo` and `bar`.

How should I change my setup to make this work the way I want? If possible, I would prefer not to move `foo.py` and `bar.py` out of `lib` into the top level of the project.